# Node.js + ExpressJS + Flask

Tags: node.js, express, flask

I am helping building a web app where the UI has been built using Flask API. The functionality that I am meant to create can only be built with Javascript so I was thinking on building on the Node.js environment using Express. Is it possible to still use the UI that has been built with python?

I need some advise on how these different frameworks can work together.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use both together if you do some workarounds. By keeping the UI in Flask on your port, you could try using the Express app on a different port, e.g. 3000. So, you would have them listening on different ports and you could just send your requests to a different port, like this:

```
<script>
  fetch("yourwebsiteip:3000/api/hello");
</script>
```

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but I would like post this just to give an idea.

Happy coding!!!